# to ban sth from/in/at?

Tags: prepositions

I want to talk about the banning of plastic at/in/from schools.

I just wondered which preposition is the best or the right one?

The sentence is:

> Teachers are in favor of banning plastic at/from/in Maximilian Gymnasium (name of school).

AND

> Teachers are against banning plastic at/from/in Maximilian Gymnasium.

Which preposition(s) would work best?

Comment: Please include your research.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Please consider [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5043/71848).

Comment: Okay. Well, I don't really know what to research. The issue is that I think all three prepositions could work. But I wondered which one fits best for my issue. I want to say that all plastic related items are neither allowed to be brought into school from  school staff or students nor are any (old) plastic related items allowed to be in school anymore.

Comment: Did you look which combinations of prepositions are used? Did you compare how common each combination is (e.g. using ngrams)?

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering. But I am not a native speaker. If I knew the answer, I wouldn't have asked. But thanks for the ngrams advice. I checked it and each cases are used more or less equally.

Comment: Please have a look here http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=ban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those prepositions work, but not all of them convey the same meaning.

1) From

> Teachers are in favor of banning plastic from Maximilian Gymnasium.

This is the most natural preposition and likely captures your intended meaning: that teachers want the school to enforce a "no plastic" policy. "Banning/banned from" is a fairly standard usage. For example:

> I've been banned from the chat room.

2) At

> Teachers are in favor of banning plastic at Maximilian Gymnasium.

Essentially conveys the same meaning as 1. You could maybe argue that the meaning is more along the lines of, "We will not tolerate the use of plastic at our school." as opposed to "Eliminate all current and future plastic from these grounds." But I think that's a stretch, and it's more or less identical to 1.

Edit: note, however, that its usage depends on the context. It would not be natural, for example, to say "I've been banned at the chat room."

3) In

> Teachers are in favor of banning plastic in Maximilian Gymnasium.

Though grammatically correct, this is likely not the intended meaning in your example. The preposition "in" should only be used in place of "at" when it's literally referring to being inside a given place or institution (i.e., within the walls of the school building).

Here, the meaning is definitely different from those of the others: in particular, it could imply that the use of plastic *outside* the school, but still *on school grounds*, would be acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for you in-depth explanation. Helped a lot.

Comment: @Phil No problem. I edited my post slightly for "at" to clarify that it can't always be used in place of "from." Hopefully it's clearer.